# Linq2DB: Bulk copy failing for float type column in MS Sql server

Tags: linq2db

I am trying to perform bulk copy for into a table that has few fields that are of type "float" in MS SQL Server. I noticed that after bulk copy completed, all these "Float" fields had value of "NULL". These fields allowed null value so these NULLs were there.
I traced the call in SQL Profiler and noticed that "INSERT BULK" command did not have these "float" fields.
I simplified my case to just simple object as below.

```
public class TestIt
    {
        public int Id{get;set;}
        public string Title { get; set; } = $"Title{DateTime.UtcNow}";
        public double? Price { get; set; }
    }
```

The table has following schema.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestIt](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Price] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestIt] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I execute BulkCopy for a list of these object, I can see that "Title" field was copied correctly. Where was "Price" field always have NULL.

Is this some limitation in Linq2Db or I am doing something wrong.

When I use bulk copy with EF, it works fine.

Comment: Probably you have to add [Column] attribute and specify which type has column in database.

Comment: I just did an experiment by changing fields from "float" to "numeric" and it works fine. Question still remains that is "float" not supported?

Comment: We tried to reproduce with information from the question - everything works fine. Probably we need more details.

Comment: Please specify linq2db version and SQL server version `select @@VERSION`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5014356) - 15.0.2095.3 (X64), Lin2DB V3.6

Comment: I have resolved it by adding explicit column-field type mapping using WithColumn(Price).AsFloat()